# Is there a way to avoid re-importing packages each time script must be executed again?

Tags: python, pandas

I wonder, if there a way to "constantly" load python packages and keep them assessible? I mean, assuming I have a basic flask app with three scripts with some functions. Each script has some basic imports like

```
#script1.py  
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

#script2.py  
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np  

#script3.py  
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np  
import smth else and heavyweight
```

So each time the scripts are called from main.py the importing will be started. Is there a way to import all the packages once? Like, if they were somewhere "in cloud" and I just refer to them when I need to.

I thought to create one .py script with all the needed imports in function and make them so to say global, but unsure if it's ok

Comment: Each process has its own memory and needs to import its own packages

Comment: @MadPhysicist so no way? :( too bad, but I thought so

Comment: You can create a script with imports as you mentioned, probably not common practice but surely useful, they do that in [fastai](https://github.com/fastai/fastai/blob/master/fastai/imports/core.py)

Comment: You might be able to run a process that runs in the background and does some truly weird stuff with shared memory, but I can assure you that you don't want to do that.

Comment: Keep in mind that your three imports are just done once.

Comment: You should time these imports. They likely don't take more than a fraction of a second. I wouldn't worry about optimizing something that you haven't determined to be a bottleneck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from being permanent between processes, python imports happen pretty much exactly how you want already. The statement `import pandas` (with or without the `as pd`), as well as `from pandas import ...` go something like this:

- Check if the dictionary `sys.modules` has an entry for `'pandas'`. If so, return it.
- Otherwise, create an empty module object and insert it as `sys.modules['pandas']`
- Load the module in `.../pandas/__init__.py` into the empty module

Notice that any occurrence of `import pandas` after the first will just reference the global `sys.modules['pandas']`, not perform a from-scratch import. The reason that an empty object is created first is to avoid problems with circular imports.

If `script1` imports `script2` and vice-versa, you will not go into an infinite loop:

- `script1` exists as an empty object in `sys.modules['script1']`
- Somewhere in populating the empty namespace, `script1` encounters `import script2`
- `script2` is creates as an empty object `sys.modules['script2']`
- Somewhere in populating the empty namespace, `script2` calls `import script1`
- The import returns the partially initialized `script1` object already in `sys.modules`, and does not attempt to load `script1` again from scratch. `script1` may not be fully populated, so using its attributes may not work, but that is a different problem.

So the python import system already handles everything at a global level through `sys.modules`, just not across different processes. However, all scripts run from a single `main` module will have access to the exact same set of imported module objects, which only get loaded from disk once.